# How to validate a dynamic form in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a form dynamically generated according to data comes from API. I succeed to implement the form completely although I'm still getting an error whenever I try to call 'form.valid' method.

Here is a snippet of my code :

**Template File**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="update()" [ngFormModel]="questionsForm">

   <div *ngFor="#question of questions; #i=index" >
        <input type="hidden" #questionInput [value]="'qu['+(question.id)+']'" class="hidden"/>

        {{addControlName(questionInput.value)}}

        <div class="col-xs-11">
            <input type="text" ngControl="{{questionInput.value}}" name="{{questionInput.value}}[title]"
  [(ngModel)]="question.title" >
            <label >Title</label>
            <control-message [control]="questionInput.value" ></control-message>
        </div>
        <!-- Some More fields -->
        <!-- Some More fields -->
        <!-- Some More fields -->
    </div>
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
    <!--<button type="submit" [disabled]="!questionsForm.valid"> Submit</button>-->
</form>
```

**Component Class**

```
export class QuestionsComponent {

   private questionsForm;
   private questions:Array<Question>;
   private errors:any = {};

   constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder) {

   } 

   ngOnInit() {
       this.questionsForm = new ControlGroup({});
   }

   addControlName(name) {
       if (!this.questionsForm.contains(name)) {

           var control = new Control("", Validators.compose([Validators.required]));

           this.questionsForm.addControl(name, control);

       }
   }

   removeQuestion(questionId:string) {

       this.questions = this.questions.filter((question:Question) => {

           if (question.id != questionId) {
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       });
   }

   newQuestion() {

       // this.questions.push(newQuestion); here I append question whenever the user clicks on 'add new question' button.
   }

   private _setErrors(errors:any):void {
       this.questionsForm.response = errors;

       ValidatorService.setErrors(errors.errors, this.questionsForm);
   }

   private getQuestions():void {
        // this.questions = Question.castArray(data.data); here I load questions from external source.
   }
}
```

As you can see the form loads questions from an external source, the user is able to add new questions or remove some other questions.
The input controls identifier is dynamically generated I keep it in a local variable in the template 'questionInput' then I use this to add the control to my control group 'addControlName' the I define ngControl.

The code before is a snippet, the complete code is working completely I can see errors whenever I get an error response or I miss any of the questions. The problem comes whenever I use 'questionsForm.valid' rather than in template or component it self, It gives me this error :

```
EXCEPTION: Expression '!questionsForm.valid in QuestionsComponent@308:36' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true' in [!questionsForm.valid in QuestionsComponent@308:36]

ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression '!questionsForm.valid in QuestionsComponent@308:36' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'
```

Did I do anything in a wrong way, I'm new to Angular, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here you have more info about Dynamic Forms in Angular 2: https://playcode.org/dynamic-forms-in-angular-2/

Comment: Hey did you came up with a solution?